# How to get sum of formatted money values on a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to get the total value of a column containing money values. In the code below, it can obtain the sum of values ​​that do not contain a currency symbol. However, it throws an error in a column with a value such as "98.85€". All my columns have a money symbol in them. How can I collect them all?

```
 Decimal sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        }
```

My string format for datagridview column

```
 Validsum = string.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:c}", sum);
```

Comment: What you can do is to sum the values of the underlying data, which of course contains values expressed in `decimal`. Right? -- If you want to use the DataGridView Cell's `Value`, cast `Value` to `decimal`, since of course the data Type of the Column is actually `decimal`, not string. Right?

Comment: If you're currency symbol is `€`, the decimal separator is most likely `,` not `.`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
decimal val = 0;

NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
CultureInfo cultureInfo1 = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");

//try to convert the value to Decimal
Decimal.TryParse(textBoxInput.Text, style, cultureInfo1, out val);
```

Also see the following:

- [DataGridViewCell.EditedFormattedValue Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.editedformattedvalue?view=net-5.0)
- [DataGridViewCell.FormattedValue Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCell_FormattedValue)
- [DataGridViewCell.Value Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value?view=net-5.0)

**Resources**:

- [CultureInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0#Invariant)
- [Decimal.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Decimal__)
- [NumberStyles Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-5.0)
- [IFormatProvider Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=net-5.0)
- [Decimal TryParse convert currency string to decimal](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69977a37-30c2-4971-99fd-b8307dc1722e/decimal-tryparse-convert-currency-string-to-decimal?forum=csharpgeneral)